# Conversion failed when adding percentage to end of value

Tags: sql, casting, percentage

```
,CASE WHEN 
   sq.Total_Sales > 0 THEN 
   CAST(ROUND(CAST(sq.Total_Sales AS FLOAT) / (SUM(pfm.C1)) * 100,0) AS varchar(10)) + '%'
   ELSE 0 
   END AS Conversion_Rate
```

Please can someone help with why I am unable to add % at the end?
I am getting a "conversion failed when converting the varchar value '25%' to data type int" error.

Example data:

[image]

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `ROUND(... * 100, 0)` - 0 is the second argument to `ROUND`.

Comment: SQL Server 2008

Comment: @MarcinJ You're right...let me edit to make it clearer.

Comment: What's the exact error message? And what are the base data types of those columns?

Comment: I'm confused, so are you having an issue converting to an `INT` or are you having an issue adding the `%` to the end? Or both?

Comment: @forpas No, as Marcin pointed out already, the `,0` is the second parameter to `ROUND`.

Comment: Sorry please see revised question - I am trying to add percentage to the end and i am getting a "conversion failed when converting to data type int " error

Comment: Can you confirm everything before the `+ '%'` is working? Does it return a number?

Comment: You'll need to post the entire query, there's nothing here that could cause such an issue. My suspicion is that either you have a condition somewhere else that might be casting something to int, or `pfm.C1` is not of a numeric type, like a varchar, and contains something that can't be casted correctly.

Comment: [I can't reproduce your error](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4633f3c8165f1a2b6e66557585c6fdd4) using your query with dummy values.  Please add sample data to make this a reproducible problem.

Comment: Updated as above

Comment: The "number" zero (i.e. `0`) could be considered an integer, while the "string" `'0'` might not be, if you see what I'm hinting at here.

Comment: As an aside, I recommend returning the raw number for Conversion_Rate, and let your UI (report, webpage, etc) handle the formatting to percent, or whatever it wants.

Answer (score 0):

So a column returned from a query can only be of a single type, right? When looking at your query, the db engine sees two types in the `CASE` statement:

- `CAST(ROUND(CAST(sq.Total_Sales AS FLOAT) / (SUM(pfm.C1)) * 100,0) AS varchar(10)) + '%'` produces `VARCHAR(11)`
- `0`, in the `ELSE` part, is an `INT`

The database engine tries to consolidate them both to INT, and since '5%' can't be casted to an INT, you get an error. You need to change your `ELSE 0` to something producing a `varchar`, like `ELSE '0%'` or even `ELSE ''`.

Comment: Thank you!! Such a simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

It appears SQL Server does not approve of your attempt to potentially use the *integer* literal `0` in a string concatenation. Whether or not this would or could *actually happen* is another story. It matters not, as SQL Server will require you to use strings to concatenate strings--even when the theoretical path to concatenation is not possible.

Try this:

```
,CASE WHEN 
   sq.Total_Sales > 0 THEN 
   CAST(ROUND(CAST(sq.Total_Sales AS FLOAT) / (SUM(pfm.C1)) * 100,0) AS varchar(10)) + '%'
   ELSE '0' 
   END AS Conversion_Rate
```